# Unable to install Android for Windows 7 because JDK is not found

Tags: windows, java, android, installer, jdk

I have JDK SE7u4 installed in windows 7. I tried to install Android on Windows 7 using the `installer_r18-windows.exe` but no avail.

The setup window showed the message saying that the Java SE JDK not found and

> ERROR: Failed to find Java version for C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
> The system cannot found the file specified.
>
> If you believe you have a JDK installed and it was not properly recognized, simply set an environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to it

I right clicked on *Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment variables*. I created a NEW system variable called `JAVA_HOME` and set the value as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin` or `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe`.

I ran the installer again — the same error message still appeared.

Comment: Which version of JDK you are using?

Answer (score 5):

You might have a different problem, but here is the solution I found to the same error message:

1. Go to `C:\Windows\system32`
2. Rename `java.exe` to something else, for example `java2.exe`
3. Run Android SDK Setup again

Thanks to: http://www.androidbeats.in/android-sdk-failed-to-find-java-exe/4251/

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded Eclipse Juno and I wanted to install Android SDK too. It only worked by installing the Java JDK ['Windows x86 79.48 MB jdk-7-windows-i586.exe' from oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html) (despite the fact that I use Windows 64-bit).

Remember to uninstall every Java JDK kit from control panel first before you install the JDK above.

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  All you did was install the current version of the Java SDK.

Comment: @Ramhound, makes. he states that he installed x86 version even on 64b windows.

Answer (score 3):

As the OP commented on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/429740):

> I installed Java JDK 7u4 for windows 7 64-bit. I think the Android SDK
>   installer was trying to detect the 32-bit version of the JDK, so I
>   went to install the 32-bit version of the JDK.
>
> Then I ran the Android SDK installer again. This time the installer
>   detected the JDK and it installs the SDK. That was my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Browse To C:/Windows/system32 and find a file named "java.exe". Then, just rename it to "java2.exe". Voila ! It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had an app last week that wouldn't work with Java 7. I had to manually download the latest Java 6 from java.com, uninstal 7, then install 6, then disable Java auto-updates in the Java app in the Control Panel.

Comment: I installed Java JDK 7u4 for windows 7 64-bit. I think the Android SDK installer was trying to detect the 32-bit version of the JDK so i went to install the 32-bit version of the jdk. Then I ran the Andoid SDK installer again. This time the installer detected the JDK and it installs the SDK. That was my solution.

Comment: @user1294663 Please post your solution as an _answer_ and then accept it, so that others know your issue is resolved (and how you resolved it!). Comments such as this one are easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the android sdk installer in the administrator mode. IT worked for me. Just right click the installer and select 'run as administrator' option. Should work out

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts for a couple of days. I was not able to resolve the issue through the Android studio installer, but found a workaround:

- Go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- Instead of downloading "Android Studio package" (the exe file), scroll down and select "SDK tools package" (the zip file).
- This work perfectly and allows you to select all the packages you want to download, including the packages installed by the installer.

Comment: Probably not needed as an answer since there are many other good answers and the question is over 4 years old.